# How to know the module package?

Tags: 8, drush

I need to know the package of a given module to performs some actions inside the implementation of a custom a drush command. So usually you will find that we will found this information in the [module_handler](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21ModuleHandler.php/class/ModuleHandler/8.2.x) service. But there is not method to get the module package.

So, how can I know the module package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe another simpler way exists, but after a little digging in the core I found that the modules list (admin/modules) with all the information is retrieve from the [_system_rebuild_module_data()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!system.module/function/_system_rebuild_module_data/8.2.x) function that use the 
[info_parser](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21InfoParser.php/class/InfoParser/8.2.x) service to retrieve all the module information.

If you want to know the module package you can use this code:

```
$module_machine_name = 'views';
$module = \Drupal::service('module_handler')->getModule($module_machine_name);
$module_info = \Drupal::service('info_parser')->parse($module->getPathname());
// To use dpm() you need the devel module.
dpm($module_info['package']);
```

Output:

> Core